# regular expression presearch Pattern in python3

Tags: python-3.x

Why the symbol <kbd>**+**</kbd> of the pattern in the regular expression pre-search  is  invalid ? 
regular expression presearch Pattern in python3.

[details are as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjns7.png)
My purpose is to match the symbol dot and any number of adjacent digits to the left of dot in order to extract unmatched parts. Such as

```
"Contents156.html" -> "Contents" ; 
"PingHang12Report_ipad1_1269.html" ->"PingHang12Report_ipad1_" ;
```

But now it seems that pattern doesn't work because of "Lookaround Is Atomic". So how should I do ?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks. My purpose is to match the symbol dot and any number of adjacent digits to the left of dot in order to extract unmatched parts.  Such as "Contents156.html" -> "Contents" ;   "PingHang12Report_ipad1_1269.html" ->"PingHang12Report_ipad1_" ;  But now it seems that pattern doesn't work because of "Lookaround Is Atomic"?  So how should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `?=` which "matches next but doesn’t consume any of the string". Your `.*` matches the return value (including 2 digits) and `?=` part find a digit and dot to be the "next" part. Things matched by `?=` will not appear in the final result.

If you need a non-greedy match for `.*` part, use `.*?` instead.

```
re.findall(r'.*?(?=\d+\.)', 'PingHang12Report_ipad1_1269.html')
# => ['PingHang12Report_ipad1_', '', '', '', '']`
```

where you can just take the first element.

Another way to do this,

```
re.findall(r'(.*?)(\d+\..*)', 'PingHang12Report_ipad1_1269.html')
# => [('PingHang12Report_ipad1_', '1269.html')]
```

Comment: Thanks. My purpose is to match the symbol dot and any number of adjacent digits to the left of dot in order to extract unmatched parts.  Such as "Contents156.html" -> "Contents" ;   "PingHang12Report_ipad1_1269.html" ->"PingHang12Report_ipad1_" ;  But now it seems that pattern doesn't work because of "Lookaround Is Atomic"?  So is there any other way?

Comment: @Y.Kod Easy way to make it non-greedy, `re.findall(r'.*?(?=\d+\.)', 'PingHang12Report_ipad1_1269.html')`, this givens you `['PingHang12Report_ipad1_', '', '', '', '']` and you can simply take the first element

Comment: @Y.Kod Or you can separate the two part in case you need the rest part `r'(.*?)(\d+\..*)'`. This works fine even if there is another dot in the filename.

Comment: but i am a little confused.   pattern1:  '.*?(?=\d+\.)'  pattern2:  '.*(?=\d+\.)'  non-greedy and greedy? is there any information that can be used to understand? Thanks

Comment: @Y.Kod You can lookup https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html , search for non-greedy